# Use gconftool-2 for other users settings

Tags: gconf

if I run gconftool-2 it works with my own profile. but I'd like to tweak the other users.

is it possible to use it for other users profiles?

should I "su " and only then run gconftool-2?

May there is another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you will obviously need write access to their `.gconf/` folder.  But if you have that, I think `gconftool-2 --config-source=$THEIRHOME/.gconf/` might work.  (Untested since I'm the only user on this computer.)

Comment: For all users use:

    gconftool-2 --config-source=xml::/etc/gconf

for specific user (let's say: usernmae)
    gconftool-2 --config-source=xml::/home/$USER/.gconf

I don't have enough permissions to answer my own question. So I'm accepting yours.